# Python. Как отключить выделение текста в ScrolledText?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x200")

text_1 = ScrolledText(width=48, height=6, font=('Arial', 10, 'bold'), wrap=WORD, state=NORMAL)
text_1.insert('1.0', 'Текст в этом поле не должен реагировать на попытку выделения')
text_1.place(x=10, y=10, anchor='nw')
text_1.config(state=DISABLED)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Нашел](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54793199/5909792) вариант через отключение биндингов:

```
text_1.bindtags((str(text_1), str(root), "all"))
```

А `text_1.config(state=DISABLED)` можно удалить

**UPD.**

Добавил игнорирование события перемещения мышки и клика мышки:

```
text_1.config(state=DISABLED)
text_1.bind('<Motion>', lambda event: 'break')
text_1.bind('<Button>', lambda event: 'break')
```

Весь код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x200")

text_1 = ScrolledText(width=48, height=6, font=('Arial', 10, 'bold'), wrap=WORD, state=NORMAL)
text_1.insert('1.0', 'Текст в этом поле не должен реагировать на попытку выделения' * 10)
text_1.place(x=10, y=10, anchor='nw')

text_1.config(state=DISABLED)
text_1.bind('<Motion>', lambda event: 'break')
text_1.bind('<Button>', lambda event: 'break')

root.mainloop()
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прямой копипаст text_1.bindtags((str(text_1), str(root), "all")) отключил все взаимодействия, в том числе возможность прокрутки текста, что неприемлимо. Изучил материал по предоставленной Вами ссылке- не хватило опыта разобраться в кодовых решениях, но зато оттуда взял идею поиграть с цветами граундов выделения. Теперь выделение сливается с фоном и его не видно. Но оно существует, поэтому цель достигнута лишь частично. Но тем не менее всеравно спасибо, Ваш ответ направил меня на путь ко временному решению

Comment: @ЖеняНевейко, ну да, колесико мышки не листает текст, но если мышкой тянуть за ползунок - то листается

Comment: @ЖеняНевейко, покопался в теме и добавил новый вариант, тестировал с большим текстом, чтобы убедиться, что колесико мышки работает :)

Comment: В любом случае полезные механики, о которых я бы узнал еще не скоро, не случись Ваш месседж :)

Comment: @ЖеняНевейко, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте и примите ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Увы, основная проблема по-прежнему не решена

Comment: @ЖеняНевейко, проверял на вашем коде - у меня работает. Добавил его в ответ

Comment: Вопрос решён, ответ принят. Я извиняюсь, на "мини-примере" по непонятным причинам при запуске ползунок вёл себя неадекватно и ввёл меня в заблуждение.  В основном проекте всё сработало как надо, спасибо. Теперь проблемы нет :)

Comment: @ЖеняНевейко, пожалуйста :)